# After converting to Json object data dissapears

Tags: java, c#, json

I am making a tcp server and decided to use json for packing(i call it that).

Client is c#, server is java

Client sends:

```
byte[] b1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes({\"action\":\"login\",\"age\":20}");
```

Server:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" );  

ByteBuffer inBuff = evt.getInputBuffer();               // Input buffer

System.out.println(charset.decode(inBuff)); // out: {"action":"login","age":20}

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(charset.decode(inBuff));

System.out.println(obj.toString()); // out: {},  THE PROBLEM
```

Comment: Your client is probably mising a double quote -> byte[] b1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"action\":\"login\",\"age\":20}");

Comment: @ArghyaC If it was just that, his `System.out.println(charset.decode(inBuff));` wouldn't have produced anything reasonable.

Comment: Remove the print and try again.

Comment: Removed print and put String action = obj.getString("action");
Error: JSONObject["action"] not found.

Comment: No, I meant the print from *before* the assignment to `obj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert CharBuffer to String in a temporary variable then make object from that variable:

```
String temp = charset.decode(inBuff).toString();

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(temp);

String action = obj.getString("action");

System.out.println(action); //
```

Answer (score 0):

generally once read from buffer it increments the counter, so once its all read it will empty unless you add something to it later. try using line 4 before line 3, i.e.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" );  

ByteBuffer inBuff = evt.getInputBuffer();               // Input buffer

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(charset.decode(inBuff));

System.out.println(charset.decode(inBuff)); // out: {"action":"login","age":20}

System.out.println(obj.toString()); // out: {},  THE PROBLEM
```

that should give some clue as to whats going on (YOU CANNOT USE THE BUFFER TWICE)

Comment: still JSONObject["action"] not found.

Comment: `charset.decode()` returns a `CharBuffer`, so, your instantiation of JSONObject will call [link](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.Object%29). try `new JSONObject(charset.decode(inBuff).toString())` instead

Comment: When i do JSONObject obj = JSONObject(charset.decode(inBuff).toString()), obj comes empty, however i have found solution